# Is this formula for calculating the number of loops length $n$ on a square lattice correct?

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification

For a loop on an infinite square lattice where the permitted moves are $x = (0, 1)$, $x^{-1} = (0, -1)$, $y = (1, 0)$, and $y^{-1} = (-1, 0)$, we observe that there must be the same number of $x$ moves as $x^{-1}$ moves, as well as the same number of $y$ moves as $y^{-1}$ moves. If we map $x$ moves as the horizontal axis on a grid, and $x^{-1}$ moves as the vertical, and do the same thing with $y$ and $y^{-1}$ moves, then letting $c_x$ be the total number of $x$ and $x^{-1}$ and $c_y$ be the total number of $y$ and $y^{-1}$ moves, the length of the path is $n = c_x + c_y$. The number of NE paths to a point $(n,m)$ on a square lattice is given by $\binom{n + m}{m}$, so the number of valid paths for a given pair $c_x + c_y = n$ is then given by:

$$\binom{c_y}{\frac{c_y}{2}} \cdot \binom{c_x}{\frac{c_x}{2}} \cdot \binom{c_y + c_x}{c_x}$$

where the first term is the number of paths on the $c_y$ grid, the second term is the number of paths on the $c_x$ grid, and the third term is the number of ways to interleave the two. Substituting $c_y = n - c_x$ and taking the sum over all possible values of $c_x$, we then get:

$$\sum_{c_x=0}^{n}{\binom{n - c_x}{\frac{n - c_x}{2}} \cdot \binom{c_x}{\frac{c_x}{2}} \cdot \binom{n}{c_x}}$$

(which could probably be simplified further).

My question is, is this method of counting the paths correct? And if not, where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Can you be more precise about exactly what a loop of length $n$ is ? Is $(x^{-1}x) $ a loop of length 2 ?  Is $(x^{-1} xx^{-1}x)$ a loop of length 4 ? or does it have to be something like  $(x^{-1}yxy^{-1} )$

Comment: @WW1 Yes. The only requirement is that it does get back to the origin at the last step. (Although it could also not include such paths by changing $c_x=0$ in the bottom of the sum to $c_x=1$ and $n$ to $n - 1$ in the top, if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: when you use the formula $\binom{n + m}{m}$ you were not taking into account that you can move backwards there are an infinite number of paths to $(n,m)$ but only a finite number of length $N$

Comment: @WW1 I was using that formula for the number of paths on the grids defined by the movements in $x$ and $y$, rather than the original grid. On the vertical axis of the $x$ grid was the number of $x^{-1}$ moves executed so far and on the horizontal was the number of $x$ moves, with the same thing for the $y$ grid. Since you can't "undo" a move that was already done, and we are looking for paths with equal numbers of steps in either direction we can model the moves and inverses themselves as north-east lattice paths on square lattices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let $n_x$ be the number of $x$ moves, which must be the same as the number of $x^{-1}$ moves

let $n_y$ be the number of $y$ moves, which must be the same as the number of $y^{-1}$ moves

so $2(n_x + n_y) = n \equiv 2k$ (note that $n$ must be even)

The number of ways of making loops of length $n$ that contain ...

- $n_x$ $x$ moves
- $n_x$ $x^{-1}$ moves
- $n_y = k-n_x$ $y$ moves
- $n_y=k-n_x $ $y^{-1}$ moves

$$N(n_x, n) = \binom{ n}{ n_x}    \binom{ n-n_x}{ n_x}   \binom{ n-2n_x}{ k-n_x} $$

- $ \binom{ n}{ n_x} $ ways of placing the $x$ moves
- $\binom{ n-n_x}{ n_x} $ ways of placing the $x^{-1}$ moves in the remaining positions
- $ \binom{ n-2n_x}{ n_y} = \binom{ n-2n_x}{ k-n_x}   $ways of placing the $y$ moves in the remaining positions
- fill the remaining $n_y$ positions with $y^{-1}$ moves

The total number of loops
$$N( n) = \sum_{n_x=0}^k   \binom{ n}{ n_x}    \binom{ n-n_x}{ n_x}   \binom{ n-2n_x}{ k-n_x} $$